# unable to set gcloud project using bash script

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am basically trying to set google project ID by calling the bash script file but unable to do so. However, if I run the command separately it works. I am calling the bash script file by activating gcloud shell terminal.

The command: `./init.sh vibrant-brand-298097 vibrant-bucket terraform-trigger /var/dev/dev.tfvars`

init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT_ID=$1

#Bucket for storing state
BUCKET_NAME=$2

# Based on this value cloud build will set trigger on the test repository
TERRAFORM_TRIGGER=$3

# This is the path to the env vars file, terraform will pick variables from this path for the given env.
TERRAFORM_VAR_FILE_PATH=$4

#Check if all the args were passed
if [ $# -ne 4 ]; then
  echo "Not all the argumets were passed"
  exit 0
fi

echo "setting project to $PROJECT_ID"
gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID

echo "Creating bucket $BUCKET_NAME"
gsutil mb -b on  gs://$BUCKET_NAME/
```

Error log:

```
setting project to
ERROR: (gcloud.config.set) argument VALUE: Must be specified.
Usage: gcloud config set SECTION/PROPERTY VALUE [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --installation
```

Comment: Are you providing the full path of the script file when executing from gcloud terminal? Also, it's a better practice to double quote the variables: `PROJECT_ID="$1"`, `BUCKET_NAME="$2"`...so on.

Comment: Found out the issue. When I copied the script and pasted into the new `init.sh` file that I created in gcloud shell, the first line `#!/bin/bash` was not pasted. Such a minor mistake.